# why my fetched data not showing in SSR(server side rendering)/view-source:localhost:3000 page?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, server-side-rendering, nuxtjs3

I am using Nuxt 3. Can anybody help me please? in my code i have given below, isn't it should work in SSR(server side rendering)? data that i am fetching from backend using API is showing inside div of template but not showing for SSR, not appearing on view-source:localhost:3000 page. can anybody help me find the solution. i have given my codes below.

```js
export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
    const apiUrl = useRuntimeConfig().public.apiURL;
    const allCategory = ref([]);
    useFetch(async(context) => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(apiUrl + '/api/list-categories');
        const data = await response.json();
        allCategory.value = await data.all_category;
        console.log(allCategory);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error)
      }
    })
    return {
      allCategory
    }
  },

  data() {
    return {
      allCategory: [],
    }
  },
})
```

```html
<div v-for="(categoryName, index) in allCategory" :key="index">
  {{categoryName.which_category}}
</div>
```